# Notation for taking the GCD of values in a vector

Tags: notation, vectors, gcd-and-lcm

Is there any notation to take the GCD of two values in a vector? For example, if I have the following vector
$$\left[\begin{eqnarray}10\\8\end{eqnarray}\right]$$
is there a function that can be applied on the *entire* vector that returns a single value i. e. 2?

Notation for accessing the induvidual values 10 and 8 within the vector would also be sufficient.

Note that I cannot specify any of my own functions.

Comment: There is no standard notation, but you can write $\,\gcd(v_{1},v_{2}) = 2.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you!